# How to approach differential equations with separate x and y?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

I am studying population modelling, and most of the studies I looked at was in this format, which I was not familiar with.

Previously I was looking at basics such as logistic models, delayed logistic models, models with predation. In these, I was mostly dealing with N’(t) functions, and never x and y separately.

Sorry for a basic question, but answers or redirection to other sources would be appreciated.

[image: figure 1.1 is confusing]

Comment: Systems of differential equations is a huge area of study.  If this is a class I would suggest talking to your instructor, if this is self-study maybe consult the references for those two systems?